# PJSIP on iOS can't see any audio devices

Tags: ios, pjsip

I'm able to connect to the SIP provider and initiate calls (using the null audio device). I can't get it working with audio because there don't appear to be any audio devices.

```
unsigned count = 16;
pjmedia_aud_dev_info info[count];
pj_status_t stat = pjsua_enum_aud_devs(info, &count);
fprintf(stderr, "Devices: %d (status: %d)", count, stat);
```

Output is `Devices: 0 (status: 0)`

Any idea why that's returning no devices? As an iPhone, it clearly has recording and sound devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to building the necessary libraries outside of `autoconf` - the flag for `PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_COREAUDIO` wasn't being set. Once I added that to the compiler, pjsip found the audio devices.

Now if only I can get them to actually work...